# Subscribing to a cache update is not working in react-query

Tags: react-query

I'm sure this is user error.

So, I have a "product" count item at the top of my page. Whenever the products are updated, I increment that "count" by 1.

So, in a page, deep down in a component I have a "add product" button. When I click it, I use a mutation.

```
export default function useProduct (id) {
  return useMutation(
    async () => {
      return await addproduct({ id })
    },
    {
      onSuccess:(data) => {
        const { products = {} } = data?.data;

        queryClient.setQueryData(['products'], {...products });
      },
     // NOT SURE WHAT THIS 'onMutate' does.. seems to do nothing
     // as the response comes AFTER this fires....
     onMutate: async products => {
        await queryClient.cancelQueries('products');

       /* previous */
       const previousProducts = queryClient.getQueryData('products')

       /* update */
       queryClient.setQueryData('products', products)

       // Return a context object to flow thu error if needed
       return { previousProducts }
  }
  )
}
```

Now, in this top nav area, I am trying to subscribe to this "update" so I can get at the "number of products" to display the count.

```
const mutationCache = new MutationCache()

const SomeComponent = () => {
   const callback = mutation => {
     console.log("=============== ", mutation)
   }

   const values = mutationCache.subscribe(callback)
```

I also tried "queryClient" but that doesn't have a subscribe and the nav is already loaded when I click the button "add product".

I also tried "QueryCache", but that didn't fire when I "added the product". So, it wasn't subscribing.. I guess.

At this point I am just trying to get anything back. I can't.

I also tried "useQuery" but again, doesn't seem to catch the observed update from down the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // NOT SURE WHAT THIS 'onMutate' does.. seems to do nothing

`onMutate` is for optimistic updates. It is called *before* the request is fired so that you can optimistically update your cache for instant ui feedback. This is covered in [the docs here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/optimistic-updates).

if you want to update the cache *after* you get the response from the backend, use the `onSuccess` callback. This is covered in [the docs here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses).

> Now, in this top nav area, I am trying to subscribe to this "update" so I can get at the "number of products" to display the count.

For subscriptions, always use `useQuery`. There needs to be a query that retrieves all the products. You can then for example use the `select` option to only subscribe to the amount of your products:

```
const useProducts = (select) => useQuery('products', fetchProducts, { select })
```

```
const { data: products } = useProducts() // will contain all products
const { data: nrOfProducts } = useProducts(data => data.length) // will only select the length of the array of products
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. In regards to "onMutate", then what "arg" is passed and the need for this line:  queryClient.setQueryData('product', products) <--- docs suggest you are "updating"... but "updating with what?", at this stage we do not have the "new" products....

Comment: The input is the same as for the mutateFn. Have a look at the optimistic update example in the docs. User enters a todo, and before posting to the backend, we update out todoList in the cache with that input. You probably can’t always update optimistically if you don’t know what the data is gonna be, but oftentimes you can. With a toggle button it’s easy for example - flip the state. It’s also important to undo (rollback) the optimistic update in case of error, but the example also covers this.